# My laptop won't wake up after suspend or lock

Tags: suspend

My laptop (Dell Latitude 5590 without extra video card) doesn't wake up after I lock my screen. After locking it goes black and although my power-button is lighted up, the screen stays black if I press enter, escape, space or mouse-click.
I have tried X11 and Wayland, older and newer kernel-versions, I've update Gnome to version 41, I've update my BIOS and tried things like "GRUB_CMD_LINUX="nouveau.modeset=0" in grub config and it didn't work and "RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1" in grub config and it didn't work.
I also tried using lightdm instead of gdm3, but without any succes.

What can be the issue and how to solve it?

**Edit:** Using `sudo journalctl  -b 0` I've found the line `i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe A FIFO underrun`. I've looked it up and it seems to have something to do with my graphics driver. I tried changing my resolution to something that's not 16:9, and the same thing happens: screen turns to black and I can do nothing than hold the power button to shutdown.
I've tried a few things I've found on google, but without success, like adding `nouveau.runpm=0` or `i915.enable_rc6=0` to the GRUB_CMD_LINUX in the grub config.
Is there for example an alternative to the i915 drivers for my Intel OnBoard GPU? Or is this the only option?

Edit2: I have added `nomodeset` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the grub config. This fixes the issue that after locking, the screen won´t turn on again. I don´t know why this fixes it, but I'm glad I can finally lock my laptop without having to force a shutdown. Too bad now the Nightlight doesn´t work anymore. :(
The only problem I have now left is that if I do a suspend and then try to start it again, the screen stays black. I already changes my swap file to 12GB, I read that the default 2GB is not enough. Unfortunately, this doesn´t doesn't fix it.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and model of Inspiron are you using? Does the machine have an Nvidia graphics adapter? 

Comment: After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, or an intentional reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log.  `sudo journalctl  -b 0` will show the beginning of the current boot's log.

Comment: @matigo Ubuntu 20.04 and Dell Latitude 5590 (sorry, I believed it to be an Inspiron). No, it does not have an Nvidia graphics driver, since it only has an onboard Intel video card.

Comment: @waltinator This is what I see using that first command:
`jan 08 10:33:03 rh1n0-laptop rtkit-daemon[830]: Supervising 8 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.` (this line is repeated a lot)
And this: `jan 08 10:33:13 rh1n0-laptop wpa_supplicant[701]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=1 signal=-42 noise=9999 txrate=780000
jan 08 10:33:17 rh1n0-laptop systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.`
And:
`jan 08 10:33:34 rh1n0-laptop systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
jan 08 10:33:34 rh1n0-laptop systemd[1]: systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service: Succeeded.` 
Nothing weird, right?

Comment: @waltinator The second command gives a lot of output. What should I look for?

Comment: You should "process the log". Read each message, see what information it provides, then decide if it pertains to the area you're having trouble with. Many messages won't, a few will explain the problem.

Comment: @waltinator I did. See my edited message witht the result. It has something to do with the Intel graphics driver.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found an answer/workaround. I've installed KDE Plasma (Kubuntu) and all my issues are gone!
Looks like GNOME is just buggy in combination with an Intel on-board gpu.

If anyone knows why this is the case, please let me know!